# Parser pattern for monthOfYear that is not zero-padded with no literal text separation

Tags: java, jodatime

Is it possible to parse the date `8302011` using jodatime?  In a less painful format, it would look like `8/30/2011`, which I would pattern as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

What I've tried:

- Pattern `Mddyyyy`

  - `8302011` -> `Cannot parse "8302011": Value 83 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]`
  - `12302011` -> `2011-12-30T00:00:00.000Z`

Fortunately, the date is not ambiguous as `day` is always represented as two digits.  Month, however, is either one or two digits.

I realize that it would be simple enough to pad zeros on the left to 8 characters, but in this case, I am unable to do that.

Comment: Actually as I dig deeper I'm starting to question my original answer, https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L774 leads me to https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#L432

Comment: @JasonSperske You are correct.  That does work, and fortunately I am using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` so I can specify min and max digits.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can specify that in the pattern string though.

Comment: SO is a good source for input so I have taken this question to improve [my own date/time-library](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/issues/307). Thank you. Unfortunately Joda-Time (and JSR-310, too) don't support this kind of pattern. Although you have found a good workaround using the builder I suggest you to submit an issue to Joda-Time-issue-tracker. Then you might get the chance to achieve this feature in a future release of Joda-Time.

Answer (score 0):

I know the below is different from jodatime but can you try to use SimpleDateFormat to parse the date as an alternative one

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by luan on 9/12/16.
 */
public class DateTimeFormatTest {
    public SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("Mddyyyy");
    public SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    public Date getDate(String source){
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = simpleDateFormat.parse(source);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }
    public String parseStringValue(Date date){
        String result = "";
        result = simpleDateFormat2.format(date);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatTest obj = new DateTimeFormatTest();
        Date date = obj.getDate("8302011");
        System.out.println(date);
        String result = obj.parseStringValue(date);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Tue Aug 30 00:00:00 ICT 2011
08/30/2011
```